# participate or be participating

Tags: ing

Which of the following is more idiomatic?

1. List out the groups **you participate in**.
2. List out the groups **you're participating in**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe the questions are not similar. "Are you using the current template version?" asks about the template version the listener is using at the moment. However, "List out the groups you're participating in." can be interpreted as a use of the present continuous for future arrangements. Therefore, it can be equivalent to "List out the groups you will participate in.".

Comment: future arrangements require time referance. In your case I would use continuous form if the event is still ongoing. or just write "... you are in".

Comment: @hb20007: That's a spurious distinction. Just because the word "current" happens to occur in *Are you using the current template version?* doesn't imply it can't be a question about intended ***future*** activity. Both that utterance and *List out the groups you're participating in* could validly have the word ***tomorrow*** appended.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with that, however the answers on that question do not mention the possible use of the present continuous for future arrangements. Therefore, referring OP to that question would leave them with an incomplete answer.

Comment: @hb20007: The OP here never even *mentioned* whether the cited text was supposed to reference current or future action, so I can't see why we should be bending over backwards here to explain anything about that peripheral detail. Besides which, so far as I'm concerned - if it's not a duplicate or POB, this question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> List out the groups you participate in.

This sentence would be more appropriate when talking about participation over a longer period of time. E.g., when inquiring about groups that the listener regularly participates in.

> List out the groups you're participating in.

This sentence implies that the participation is either more short-lived, or will take place in the future ([present continuous for future arrangements](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/)).

### Examples

If inquiring about special interest groups at a learning institution that hold regular meetings, I would go with "List out the groups you participate in."

If inquiring about a single-day event with several groups that the attendees can participate in, I would go with "List out the groups you're participating in."

If inquiring about groups whose activities haven't started yet, I would go with "List out the groups you're participating in."